# Random distribution

Tags: c#

I want to know how i can create a random class that distributes data in a table randomly to 36 other tables without repetition and also how to print out those tables.
Am new to programming please

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "table"? 2) What do you mean by "without repetition"?

Comment: If your requirements are sufficiently low, `System.Random` might be what you need.

Comment: What do you mean randomly? and without repetition?

Comment: Its a database that stores name of graduates from each school in a country so am to design an app in C# that distributes these graduates to 36 states for their service. So there cant be repetition of names

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out the confusion around "tables", the general way you would distribute X items randomly is:

1. put them in a list,
2. pick an item at random
3. remove that item from the list
4. return to 1) while there are still items available

or in code (Using a list of numbers from 1-200 as the data to distribute)

```
static Random random = new Random();
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,200));
    while(list.Count>0)
    {
        var item = list[random.Next(0,list.Count)];
        list.Remove(item);

        // Do something with 'item'
    }
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/WBOK18374

However, if its the distribution that needs to be randomized, you could put all your items in a `Queue`, then `Dequeue` them one at a time a pick a random place to put them.

In this example, again using numbers 1-200 as the data and 36 `List<int>` as the destination the code would be something like:

```
var tables = new List<int>[36];
for(var i=0;i<36;i++)
{
    tables[i] = new List<int>();
}

var stack = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,300));
while(stack.Count>0)
{
    var next = stack.Dequeue();
    var table = tables[random.Next(0,36)];
    table.Add(next);
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/HBDWH46108

Finally, if this is SQL tables you're talking about (You didnt tag it as such, you tagged it C# - hence the answer above) then you should NOT be having 36 tables which look the same. You should have 1 table containing your data, and when it is extracted you could randomize the results. Or, when it is inserted you could randomize the allocation to whatever.

Comment: Sori..Am linking the C# app to MySQL...i already have a database GRADUATES in SQL that contains the name of the graduates.... Now i have to distribute the names into another database POSTING that has 36 tables for the 36 different states..Note: the database GRADUATE size varies per year.its not fixed..thanks

Comment: Well if you're doing all this in C# you should be able to use one of the 2 ideas I posted above to distribute your data.

Comment: I tried the codes on the link you posted and gettin the followin errors.1) the name 'Enumerable' does not exist in the current context 2) the best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments. 3) Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to string[]'.    Am using visual studio 2008 and i think the code is a console application and i cant access Linq in my reference...sori for disturbing you

Comment: @user1568350 - What version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file

Comment: You'll need a `.ToArray()` with older frameowrks as they dont have that overload of `String.Join`. My bad, sorry! Heres an example: http://rextester.com/PEGB80764

Comment: I know you probably have better things to do and am disturbing but you're the only one that has tried to help me.  Am still getting the same error. Thanks